# Get unique events from Event Log and their count

Tags: windows, powershell-2.0

I have a working script that is able to pull a report of Windows Application, Security, Setup and System logs that displays only the critical and error events in the past 30 days. However, I would also really like the script to count the number of times each reported critical or error event occurred in the past 30 days. Here's the working command:

```
Get-EventLog Application -ComputerName $server -After $starttime |
    ? { $_.entryType -Match "Error" -and "Critical" } | 
    Sort-Object EventID -Unique |
    Select-Object TimeGenerated,EventID,Source,Message | 
    ft -AutoSize -Wrap | 
    Out-File $file -Append
```

And here is an example of the output in the text file:

```
TimeGenerated       EventID Source                                      Message                                        
-------------       ------- ------                                      -------                                        
7/8/2016 1:23:20 PM       0 SQL Server Report Service                   Service cannot be started. Microsoft.ReportingS
                                                                    ervices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogEx
                                                                    ception: An internal error occurred on the repo
                                                                    rt server. See the error log for more details. 
                                                                       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.Nativ
                                                                    e.GetSid(String name, Int32& length)           
                                                                       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.Nativ
                                                                    e.NameToSid(String name)                       
                                                                       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.Servi
                                                                    ceAppDomainController.StartRPCServer(Boolean fi
                                                                    rstTime)                                       
                                                                       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.Servi
                                                                    ceAppDomainController.Start(Boolean firstTime) 
                                                                       at Microsoft.ReportingServices.NTService.Rep
                                                                    ortService.OnStart(String[] args)              
                                                                       at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Service
                                                                    QueuedMainCallback(Object state)               
7/8/2016 1:23:20 PM     121 Report Server Windows Service (MSSQLSERVER) The Remote Procedure Call (RPC) service failed 
                                                                    to start.
```

It would be great to have another column in the results that displays the occurrences of each EventID in the specified time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like so (line 3 & 4 are new and `Count` in `Select-Object`)
Technically you could also remove the `-Unique` from `Sort-Object` as after grouping them and passing through only the first item of the group  is more or less the same.

```
Get-EventLog Application -ComputerName $server -After $starttime | 
    ? { $_.entryType -Match "Error" -and "Critical" } |
    Group-Object -Property EventID |
    % { $_.Group[0] | Add-Member -PassThru -NotePropertyName Count -NotePropertyValue $_.Count } |
    Sort-Object EventID -Unique | 
    Select-Object Count, TimeGenerated, EventID, Source, Message | 
    ft -AutoSize -Wrap | 
    Out-File $file -Append
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later tonight.

Comment: Yes. I had to change the Add-Member command to `Add-Member -PassThru -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Count -Value $_.Count }`, but otherwise it works beautifully. Thanks!